# React Native Color Issue

Tags: android, react-native, package

I'm having a problem with colors of my app the issue occurs when I changed the package name in android.

**This is the original color when i didn't change the package name**
[image]

**After when package name changed**
[image]

I clean the gradle using `./gradlew clean` and clear cache using `react-native start --reset-cache` but still the color is not the same to the original. Do you have any idea how this happen? thank you.

Comment: Please refer which package name you have been changed.

Comment: @Marfin.F i followed this https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/how+to+change+package+name+in+react+native

Comment: Is the colors defined in your NEW_ID/MainApplication.java? or commonly is it defined in res/values? please show us how do you define those colors. Thank you

Comment: @Marfin.F The colors define in react native assets folder. I tried running in different phone and is seems like there's no problem. The bug occurs only in my phone and i don't know why. My phone is xiaomi mi 10 lite.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `Dark Mode` in my app settings is affecting my mobile app. My solution is adding `<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>` in res/styles.xml